# Problems with bad characters in UTF8 JSON strings with Delphi XE

Tags: json, delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe

We have a Delphi XE application that exchanges JSON data with a cloud application that is written in Node.

Generally everything works fine - but every once in a while we get bad (unknown) characters in some of our strings - and we are having problems tracking it down. These characters are rendered as diamonds and have a character code of `65533`

We perform a rest POST call to get our data from the cloud and we get it as a JSON object that includes some meta-data and an array of record. We use DBXJson's TJsonObject for the json parsing in the form of

```
jsv := TJSONObject.parseJsonValue(s)
```

where s is the data we got from our Post call.

From this we use a TJsonArray to get the record, traverse it and use the JSonValue.ToString to retrieve the string value.

The data is stored in DBIsam using VarChar fields.

Any ideas how to detect and prevent "bad" characters that appear or where else this could happen?

Comment: 65533 is `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which means the data went through a charset conversion using a charset that does not support the original Unicode codepoint(s) that got replaced.  But where is U+FFFD coming from exactly?  Is it already present in `s` before calling `parseJsonValue()`, or does it exist in the resulting tree that you are traversing? If the former, then double-check that your REST logic is handling the JSON string data correctly from socket to parser.

Comment: My guess is that you are likely losing the data when reading it from the REST socket, such as if the JSON is UTF-8 encoded (which is JSON''s default charset) but you are not treating it as UTF-8 when converting the raw bytes to a `String`.